# AWS S3 Bucket policy with DENY effect to Load Balancer logs from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The below S3 bucket policy to access alb logs from another account of same region with Deny policy doesn't work, I tried with a Condition but no luck
If I use "Allow" it works but I need to use Deny as per my company policy and allow based on condition

127311923021 - us-east-1

Any ideas please?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "arn:aws:s3:::myelbogs/prefix/*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myelbogs/prefix/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root"
                }
            },
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myelbogs/prefix/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            },
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myelbogs",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root"
                }
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can use [S3 Object Ownership](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-s3-object-ownership-enables-bucket-owners-to-automatically-assume-ownership-of-objects-uploaded-to-their-buckets/) rather than denying uploads without `bucket-owner-full-control`.

Comment: The policy shown doesn't provide *any* access to the bucket. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve here? It's not clear from your post.

Comment: 1. We want alb logs to written into another aws account of same region      2. To do that, as per aws document, we have to use "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root".   3. This works and able to write love with Effect=Allow...4. But, per my company policy, all bucket policies should have deny effect with a condition where I wrote above aws:arn:xxx but it didn't work...

Comment: If you aren't allowed to add `Allow` policies to your S3 bucket policy then you cannot possibly allow access to that bucket via the bucket policy. You might consider creating an IAM role with bucket permissions in the same AWS account as the bucket is, and allow the remote account to assume that cross-account IAM role.

Comment: Allow policy - which is working

Here --> 127311923021 - us-east LB id

            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root"  
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elblogs/prefix/*"

Now, I changed this to Deny - didn't work
"Effect": "Deny",
"NotPrincipal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::127311923021:root"
           },
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elblogs/prefix/*",
"Condition": {
"ArnNotEquals": {
aws:arn": "arn:aws:sts::<acct_id>:assumed-role/role_for_b/*"

Comment: Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. To access a bucket, it either needs an Allow in a Bucket Policy, or an Allow on the IAM User/IAM Role. Without any Allows, there is no access.